# How is OndestroyView called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-handler, fragment-lifecycle

Say I have a `Fragment` and I have posted on UI `handler` from background thread, a runnable to modify `Fragment` before `onDestroyView` of `Fragment` was called.

Is the posted `runnable` guaranteed to be called before `onDestroyView` will be called or can `onDestroyView` be called before the `runnable` has a chance to execute?

Answer (score 0):

If the handler is on a background thread, then it is not guaranteed to complete before `onDestroyView` is called. If you need the logic to run before `onDestroyView`, it is best to call it in the fragment's `onStop()` method.